# How to access standard component details inside custom component in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, custom-component

**I am creating a community in the financial Services cloud where I have used a standard component(tab) and inside the tab I am placing my custom component that I have created. The name that I have given to the tab is Business Acocunt. Is it possible to access the tab name inside my custom component to use it and display data accordingly?**

Answer (score 0):

No, your component doesn't have access to attributes of the component(s) which contain it. Your component would need to expose its own attribute where you could set the desired value in Lightning App Builder or the Community builder.